# How to Serialize collection

Tags: c#, iserializable

I have class with property of type ISet. I want to serialize that class but don't know how to do with ISet.

```
[Serializable]    
class Question: ISerializable
{
  private int id;
  public int Id
  {
    get{return id;}
    set{id = value;}
  }

  private ISet answerChoice;
  public ISet AnswerChoices
  {
   get{return answerChoices;}
   set { answerChoices = value; }
  }

  public Question(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  {
       id = info.GetInt32("id");
       answerChoices = //how to deserialize this collection
  }

  void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
  {
       info.AddValue("id", id);
       info.AddValue("ac", answerChoices);
  }
}
```

Do anyone try to make the same? Please, help me.

Comment: Are you talking about the ISet<T> generic interface introduced in .Net 4.0? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081.aspx

Comment: I mean Iesi.Collections.ISet from NHibernate, but If you change ISet to IList my question don't change.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
info.GetValue("ac",...);
```

And why do you implement you own serialization if you do not add any additional value?

Comment: And why do you implement you own serialization if you do not add any additional value? --- To add object to ViewState you should implement ISerializable interface - it is a rule! 

How about: info.GetValue("ac",...); --- What I should write in place of ellipsis?

Comment: No you do not, you just need to mark it as serializable(and make sure it is serializable)

Comment: @Kate, info.GetValue("ac", typeof(ISet)) should work.
@Alex, @Kate - note that for serialization to work as above, type implementing ISet has to be serializable.

Comment: Thank you very mutch. It is so simple, why i don't think about it!